# Setting TextView contents from HTML cuts off part of the text

Tags: android, textview

I'm filling the contents of a `TextView` from an HTML source using `Html.fromHtml` method, but the text appears to be italic for some reason and the first few letters are clipped. I tried `.clearComposingText()` and that didn't help.

Any idea why?

Here's the bastard:

```
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="120dip" android:duplicateParentState="false">
        <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="120dip" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/textDetailsScrollable" android:textStyle="normal" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="4dip" android:paddingRight="10dip" />
        </ScrollView>
        <ProgressBar android:layout_height="15dip" android:id="@+id/loadingExtendedData" android:layout_width="15dip" android:indeterminateOnly="true" android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

(It's not the `ScrollView`, I tried removing it and it didn't work, neither did padding on any of the elements).

Answer (score 0):

Learned the hard way: **NEVER USE ITALIC TEXT IN ANDROID**.
And if you want to strip HTML tags - use `String.replaceAll("<(.|\n)*?>", "")`.